# How to insert many unique rows via INSERT in mysql?

Tags: mysql

You know, you can duplicate an entry in a table like so;

```
INSERT INTO `clubs`( `id_leagues`, `name`, `created`) SELECT id_leagues, name, created FROM clubs WHERE id = 36 LIMIT 1
```

..where my primary key "id" is an auto_increment integer

My question is, is there a way to create ... say 10 entries in a similar way, **without** using a loop in my php script. Maybe a loop in mysql?

thanks for help

**UPDATE**

It should insert the same column 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to insert 10 records with the same conditions:

```
INSERT INTO `clubs`( `id_leagues`, `name`, `created`) 
SELECT id_leagues, name, created FROM clubs WHERE id = 36 LIMIT 10
```

And with another conditions:

```
INSERT INTO `clubs`( `id_leagues`, `name`, `created`) 
SELECT id_leagues, name, created FROM clubs WHERE id IN (36,37,38,40,45,55)
```

And in PHP if you queries are too complicated to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, you can select required data, form a single bulk insert query and execute it:

```
$query = "SELECT id_leagues, name, created FROM clubs WHERE id = 36 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM));
$data = array_fill(0, 9, "('".mysql_real_escape_string($row[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row[1])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($row[2])."')");

$query = "INSERT INTO `clubs`( `id_leagues`, `name`, `created`) VALUES " . implode(',', $data);

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: no that does not work with Limit 10. And I don't want to insert different cols, but the same 10 times.

Comment: If it is okay to use PHP, I'd select one row using it, prepare the bulk insert and execute it.

Comment: yes I know how to do this. The question is, how u can handle the problem with mysql...

Comment: I've added a sample solution to my post.

Answer (score 0):

No problem :) Select more than one tupel in your select statement.

```
INSERT INTO "table" ("col1", "col2", ...)
SELECT "col3", "col4", ...
FROM "table2"
```